# REST API Firestore authentication with ID Token

Tags: rest, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Firestore DB and one user. I am able to retrieve an ID Token for the user after they sign-in via a request with REST.

I am to use the ID Token with requests to read/write from the DB.

I am able to read and write to the Firestore when the security rules are open (anyone can read/write) in this manner, with Python requests:

```
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}

url = 'https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/[PROJECT_NAME]/databases/(default)/documents/[COLLECTION]/[DOCUMENT]'

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

Writing is similar, and omitted.

Attempting to append the ID Token as indicated by [these docs for Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/auth#authenticate_with_an_access_token) gives the error message `""Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"auth\""...`

My question is how to authorise a user ID Token for Firestore via REST?

Comment: Could you share some of your code for this?  I am trying to do something similar with Firebase Realtime database.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [Cloud Firestore REST API guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/use-rest-api#authentication_and_authorization),

> After you obtain either a Firebase ID token or a Google Identity OAuth
>   2.0 token, pass it to the Cloud Firestore endpoints as an Authorization header set to Bearer {YOUR_TOKEN}.

So your request should include the header

```
'Authorization': `Bearer ${YOUR_TOKEN}`
```